# How to simplify polynomials in sqrt() to its absolute value of factor in maxima?

Tags: simplify, sqrt, maxima

`sqrt(a^2+2*a+1)` can be easily rewritten as `|a+1|`. I would like to do this in maxima, however cannot make it work. Although `sqrt(a^2)` is automatically simplified to `|a|`, `sqrt(a^2+2*a+1)` is not. And `radcan(sqrt(a^2+2*a+1))` give `a+1`, which is incorrect. Is there anyway to get the right simplification in Maxima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Basically, you just have to tell Maxima to try a bit harder to factorise the inside of the square root. For example:

```
(%i1) x: sqrt(a^2 + 2*a + 1);
                                    2
(%o1)                         sqrt(a  + 2 a + 1)
(%i2) factor(a^2 + 2*a + 1);
                                          2
(%o2)                              (a + 1)
(%i3) map (factor, x);
(%o3)                             abs(a + 1)
(%i4)
```

The `map` here means that the function `factor` should be applied to each of the arguments of `sqrt`. What happens is that you get `sqrt((a+1)^2)` appear on the way, and this is automatically simplified to `abs(a+1)`.

Note that the answer from `radcan` is correct for some values of `a`. As I understand it, this is all that `radcan` guarantees: it's useful for answering "Yikes! Is there a simpler way to think about this crazy expression?", but not particularly helpful for "Hmm, I'm not sure what the variables in this are. Is there a simpler form?"